# match data sample matlab

Tags: matlab, data-binding, cluster-analysis, matching

Ok this is going to sound really confusing but I will try my best to make it clear enough. I have a full dataset called `fulldata` this dataset is `494021x6`.

I use svds (singular value decomposition) on it like so:

```
%% dimensionality reduction 
columns = 6
[U,S,V]=svds(fulldata,columns);
```

I then randomly select 1000 rows from the `fulldata`:

```
%% randomly select dataset
rows = 1000;
columns = 6;

%# pick random rows
indX = randperm( size(fulldata,1) );
indX = indX(1:rows)';

%# pick columns in a set order (2,4,5,3,6,1)
indY = indY(1:columns);

%# filter data
data = U(indX,indY);
```

I then apply normalization to this randomly selected 1000 rows:

```
% apply normalization method to every cell
maxData = max(max(data));
minData = min(min(data));
data = ((data-minData)./(maxData));
```

I then output a datasample from the original `fulldata` set which matches the 1000 selected rows:

```
% output matching data
dataSample = fulldata(indX, :)
```

Also note that when I picked "random rows" I also output the indX rows which match the rows in the fulldata.

So `datasample` looks like this:

[image]

Which is the 1000 random rows which match the original fulldata.

And `indX` looks like this:

[image]

Which is the corresponding row number from `fulldata`.

The problem im arriving at is when I use K-Means to cluster the 1000 random rows and I output the data of each cluster like so:

```
%% generate sample data
K = 6;
numObservarations = size(data, 1);
dimensions = 3;

%% cluster
opts = statset('MaxIter', 100, 'Display', 'iter');
[clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data, K, 'options',opts, ...
'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',3);

%% plot data+clusters
figure, hold on
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 5, clustIDX, 'filled')
scatter3(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 100, (1:K)', 'filled')
hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
grid on
view([90 0]);

%% plot clusters quality
figure
[silh,h] = silhouette(data, clustIDX);
avrgScore = mean(silh);

% output the contents of each cluster
K1 = data(clustIDX==1,:)
K2 = data(clustIDX==2,:)
K3 = data(clustIDX==3,:)
K4 = data(clustIDX==4,:)
K5 = data(clustIDX==5,:)
K6 = data(clustIDX==6,:)
```

How can I match K1, k2... K6  to the corresponding indX row number? For instance K1's output looks like this:

[image]

I was hoping to have extra files like `K1-indX` which is just a list of corresponding row numbers from `indX` which match the cluster data from K1, K2... etc. Or possibly append the indX row number into the K1, K2 output in column 7 (preferable)

For instance:

```
K1 cluster data | Belongs to fulldata row number
0.4 0.5 0.6 0.4 | 456456 etc
```

Comment: An advice for the future: when posting questions, try to minimize the code to only the relevant parts. Link to your previous questions if you think it will give additional context. Come up with simplified examples (MWE) that others can test to reproduce the problem... For example, remove all the plotting in your above code as it irrelevant to the issue here. Also you could do without mentioning the SVD decomposition and normalization (simply state that `data` is a subset of the `fulldata` by picking rows at random). I assure you, you will get more answers that way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example to illustrate:

```
%# lets use an example data of size 150x4
load fisheriris
fulldata = meas;

%# pick 100 rows at random
rIdx = randperm(size(fulldata,1));
rIdx = rIdx(1:100)';                  %#'
data = fulldata(rIdx,:);

%# cluster the subset data
K = 3;
clustIDX = kmeans(data, K);

%# divide the data according to which cluster instances were assigned to
groupedIdx = cell(K,1);
groupedData = cell(K,1);
for i=1:K
    %# instances
    groupedData{i} = data(clustIDX==i,:);

    %# corresponding row indices into the original fulldata
    groupedIdx{i} = rIdx(clustIDX==i);
end

%# check: these two should be equal
groupedData{1}(1,:)
fulldata(groupedIdx{1}(1),:)
```

Comment: Amro whats the difference in your method and `K1 = indX(clustIDX == 1), :)... 2,3,4 etc` my output shows the rows in cluster 1 to 6?

Comment: @JungleBoogie: if you meant `indX(clustIDX==1)`, then its the same as `groupdIdx{1}` in the above code. While `data(clustIDX==1,:)` is my `groupedData{1}`. Instead of creating multiple variables, I simply store the results in cell arrays. I figured a complete example (that you could copy-paste) would help you understand

Comment: Ahhh thanks Amro that iteration completely went over my head when I first looked at it, that has saved quite abit of time rather than creating multiple outputs! +1

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am mis-interpreting something above, you already have (in `indX`) the `fulldata` row numbers... All you need to do to see, for example, the rows from `fulldata` in cluster 1 is:

```
fulldata(indX(clustIDX == 1), :)
```

`kmeans` does not re-order the data, so each row 1:1000 of clustIDX still corresponds to the same row 1:1000 of `data` / `datasample` that you started with.

Said another way, `clustIDX` is going to be a vector of length 1000 where each element is the (integer) cluster assignment for that row. Thus you can use this for logical indexing anywhere you have 1000 rows in an order corresponding to the sample `data` you used for clustering.

Comment: Hey Kaelin this outputs the original data which belongs to cluster 1 which is fine but it does not append the indX row number to tell me which of the points in cluster 1 belong to which row from fulldata. I would have to manually cross check all points in cluster 1 with fulldata?

Comment: If I understand your question and Kaelin's answer, I think just `indX(clustIDX == 1)` will have the row numbers you need.